# phpize issues on mac os with MAMP

Tags: php, macos, tags, mp3, id3

Well, again I'm trying to install id3 php on MAMP on MAC OS X YOSEtime 10.10.2 according to manual from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103962/installing-pecl-id3-extension-on-ubuntu).
I used `pear update-channels` it updated

```
Updating channel "doc.php.net"
Channel "doc.php.net" is up to date
```

others were up to date.

```
pecl install --force id3
```

of course gives me `config.mp4 not found` 
I've found directory:

```
/private/tmp/pear/cache/
```

`id3-0.2.tgz` was saved there.

So I've extracted it there. Changed directory to id3-0.2 and run `phpize` there. It says:

```
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
grep: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:        
Zend Module Api No:     
Zend Extension Api No:
```

So there is no point to use next commands. Maybe I can configure `phpize` somehow to show it right paths to files?
Or can you advice other way to get tags from mp3 files in php?

Answer (score 0):

Found better solution http://www.getid3.org/
I've just downloaded an archive, extracted it to site directory and according to test in Readme (access /demos/demo.browse.php) put mp3 file to directory and I can see it's tags. Fine library.